# Список Page C# WPF

Tags: c#, mvvm

Пытаюсь щас сделать отображение билетов, как по сетке(пример ниже), создал экземпляры классов page, привел их к основному классу окна, заполнил инфу, но не знаю как через binding вывести коллекцию pages, в каком элементе тоже не имею представления, заранее спасибо за помощь[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При чем здесь коллекция `Page`, если `Page` - это View. Здесь либо MVVM не при чем и Binding не нужен, либо ваш вопрос непонятен настолько, насколько это возможно.

Comment: Кстати, если это WPF, неплохо было бы добавить тег. И покажите разметку и код приложения, подробно описав, как это работает и как оно должно работать.